# ivy resolve dependencies from different settings

Tags: maven, ant, ivy, archiva

i have configured my settings.xml in this way:

## settings.xml

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResover="archiva">
        <credentials host="host" realm="Repository Archiva Managed internal Repository" username="user" passwd="passwd" />

    </settings>
    <property name="ivy.shared.default.root" value="http://host.it/repository/internal/" override="false"/>
    <property name="ivy.shared.default.ivy.pattern" value="[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact].[ext]" override="false"/>
    <property name="ivy.shared.default.artifact.pattern" value="[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[type]s/[artifact].[ext]" override="false"/>

    <resolvers>
        <chain name="archiva">
            <ibiblio name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true"/>
            <ibiblio name="archibib" root="http://host.it/repository/internal/" m2compatible="true"/>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>    
    <modules>
        <module organisation="annogen" name="annogen" resolver="archiva" />
        <module organisation="commons-lang" name="commons-lang" resolver="archiva" />
        <module organisation="commons-codec" name="commons-codec" resolver="archiva" />
        <module organisation="commons-logging" name="commons-logging" resolver="archiva" />
        <module organisation="geniogroup.bbi" name="resutil" resolver="archiva" />                      
    </modules>

</ivysettings>
```

## Build.xml

```
<target name="resolve" description="--> take dependencies"> 
     <ivy:settings id="dependency" file="archivaIvySetting.xml" />
     <ivy:retrieve pattern="./lib" />
</target>
```

## log

> ```
> settings loaded (60ms)
> [ivy:retrieve]    default CACHE
> [ivy:retrieve]    default resolver: null
> [ivy:retrieve]    default latest strategy: latest-revision
> [ivy:retrieve]    default conflict manager: latest-revision
> [ivy:retrieve]    circular dependency strategy: warn
> [ivy:retrieve]    validate: true
> [ivy:retrieve]    check up2date: true
> [ivy:retrieve]    -- 1 resolvers:
> [ivy:retrieve]    archiva [ibiblio]
> [ivy:retrieve]        cache: null
> [ivy:retrieve]        m2compatible: true
> [ivy:retrieve]        ivy patterns:
> [ivy:retrieve]            http://host.it/repository/internal/[organisation]
> ```
>
> /[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-revision.[ext]
>
> ```
> [ivy:retrieve]        artifact patterns:
> [ivy:retrieve]            http://host.it/repository/internal/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext] 
>
> [ivy:retrieve]        repository: archiva
> [ivy:retrieve]        root: http://host.it/repository/internal/
> [ivy:retrieve]        pattern: [organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[artifact]- [revision](-[classifier]).[ext] 
> [ivy:retrieve]        usepoms: true
> [ivy:retrieve]        useMavenMetadata: true
> [ivy:retrieve]    module settings:
> [ivy:retrieve]        NONE......
>
> .......[ivy:retrieve] post 1.3 ivy file: using exact as default matcher
> [ivy:retrieve] :: resolving dependencies :: geniogroup.bbi#bpsxml;1.0
> [ivy:retrieve]    confs: [default]
> [ivy:retrieve]    validate = true
> [ivy:retrieve]    refresh = false
> [ivy:retrieve] resolving dependencies for configuration 'default'
> [ivy:retrieve] == resolving dependencies for.....
>
> .......[ivy:retrieve] :::: ERRORS
> [ivy:retrieve]    unknown resolver null
> [ivy:retrieve]    no resolver found for annogen#annogen: check your configuration
> ```

i don't understand what's wrong, i have write a resolver , i have set my settinggs for the retrieve task, but it seems that it didn't read the resolver, is there something wrong?

## Update

adding the modules task inside the settings now it retrieve the jar files, but i don't understand why i'm not able to save the jar in my workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be a typo? Your settings file is called *ivysettings.xml* and not *archivaIvySetting.xml*

```
<target name="resolve" description="--> take dependencies"> 
     <ivy:settings id="dependency" file="archivaIvySetting.xml" />
     <ivy:retrieve settingsRef="dependency" />
</target>
```

I would also like to point out that you only need the ivy settings task when you use a non-standard location for the settings file. By default it looks locally for the ivysettings.xml.

## Suggested changes

### ivysettings.xml

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResover="archiva">
        <credentials host="host" realm="Repository Archiva Managed internal Repository" username="user" passwd="passwd" />
    </settings>    
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="archiva">
            <ibiblio name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true"/>
            <ibiblio name="archibib" root="http://host.it/repository/internal/" m2compatible="true"/>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>    
</ivysettings>
```

Notes:

- Don't override the ivy default properities unless you really have to.
- Isn't it possible to get Archiva to proxy remote repositories like Maven Central? This would make the settings file even simpler:

.

```
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResover="archiva">
        <credentials host="host" realm="Repository Archiva Managed internal Repository" username="user" passwd="passwd" />
    </settings>    
    <resolvers>
       <ibiblio name="archiva" root="http://host.it/repository/proxy/" m2compatible="true"/>
    </resolvers>    
</ivysettings>
```

### build.xml

I over-used the ivy retrieve task until I discovered the power of combining configurations with the ivy cachepath task.

```
    <target name="resolve" depends="install-ivy" description="Use ivy to resolve classpaths">
        <ivy:resolve/>

        <ivy:report todir='${build.dir}/ivy-reports' graph='false' xml='false'/>

        <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path" conf="compile"/>
        <ivy:cachepath pathid="test.path"    conf="test"/>
    </target>
```

The retrieve task is only necessary when one needs to save files into the build workspace.

```
    <target name="build" depends="test" description="Create executable jar archive">
        <ivy:retrieve pattern="${dist.dir}/lib/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]" conf="runtime"/>

        <manifestclasspath property="jar.classpath" jarfile="${jar.file}">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="${dist.dir}/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </manifestclasspath>

        <jar destfile="${jar.file}" basedir="${build.dir}/classes">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${jar.main.class}" />
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.classpath}" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
```